# Regex for first and last name

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regexp where it has to match a name like: John Smith. The only rules are first and last name should start with capital letter and has to be at least 2 characters long. Also the last name has a limit of 20 characters maximum and there's a coma or white space between the names. So far I have this:

```
/[A-Z][a-z]+(\s|,)[A-Z][a-z]{19}/
```

It doesn't work when I tested it in this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html. I'm not sure what I missed. Any ideas?

Comment: (1) "Doesn't work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. (2) Why aren't you just using your browser console for testing the regex?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL, actually, I think regex is the exception where "doesn't work" is a valid problem description. In this domain, it implicitly means "doesn't match what I intend it to match" and he explained exactly what he intended it to match.

Comment: That’s a really **terrible *terrible* approach,** you know. It’s hopelessly naïve. Consider it will fail on any and all of Renée Fleming,  Tim O’Reilly, John Paul Jones, William MᶜKinley, Malcolm X, Cher, Dominique Strauss-Kahn, Federico Peña, François Mitterand, Nicolae Ceaușescu, Chiang Kai-shek, María José Márquez, José María Juárez, or Federico del Sagrado Corazón de Jesús García Lorca.

Comment: It's only for homework guys. The teacher only specifies those requirements so it's not my idea to make it simple. But thanks for all your ideas:)

Comment: @user977151, in general it's a good idea to add the tag "homework" when you are posting help with homework problems.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `{19}` to `{1,19}`. By itself, `{19}` means "match exactly 19 of the previous character". `{1,19}` means "match between 1 and 19 of the previous character".

```
/[A-Z][a-z]+(\s|,)[A-Z][a-z]{1,19}/
```

UPDATE: People are commenting that this does not meet your requirements. As you described them, it's possibly a naive implementation of your requirements, but it is just your original implementation with the bug fixed. If you are actually looking for names, a less naive implementation might be:

```
/^[A-Z][-'a-zA-Z]+,?\s[A-Z][-'a-zA-Z]{0,19}$/
```

This will catch names with apostrophes or dashes, allows a space after the comma between the names if they are separated by a comma, and allows for single-letter last names. But as the commenters have pointed out, this still fails to match a bunch of legitimate names and matches stuff that is definitely not name-like.

It also adds anchors `^` and `$` to mean the entire string must match. If you are looking for a substring, you can remove those anchors and add in word boundary checks instead:

```
/\b[A-Z][-'a-zA-Z]+,?\s[A-Z][-'a-zA-Z]{0,19}\b/
```

Comment: "U" is a perfectly valid surname.

Comment: @thg435, maybe, but that's not what the OP wants the regex to match. He specifically said, "last name should start with capital letter and has to be at least 2 characters long".

Comment: That doesn’t work for Renée Fleming or Tim O’Reilly. Or Malcolm X. Or Dominique Strauss-Kahn.  Come on guys, get real.

Comment: @BenLee: Your pattern doesn't meet these specs.

Comment: @tchrist, no, but I'm assuming by "characters" the OP meant "lowercase letters from a-z" since that what he put in his regex. He just missed the piece about `{1,19`}.

Comment: The problem is that his spec is naïve.

Comment: @thg435, no my pattern doesn't meet the specs precisely as the OP outlined in English, because it's possible to be loose with English. Instead it corrects the bug in the *code the OP posted*, which I think makes more sense.

Comment: @BenLee: their expression has more than one bug. You might want to try to correct them all.

Comment: @BenLee: unfortunately, the problem is more complicated than appears. Your expression still fails to match "Charles de Batz-Castelmore d'Artagnan", but allows a lot of rubbish like `A-------- B''''''''''--`

Comment: @thg435, I added an example of *possibly* a less naive implementation. But I would really hesitate to say their example necessarily contains more than one bug. Maybe he *knows* he has those specific requirements in the domain model for a reason you are not aware of.

Comment: @BenLee I just can’t believe how often people like the OP try to apply parochial Nineteen Fifties data-processing in the Twenty Teens. And even then it was lame.

Comment: @thg435, I know the problem is more complicated than it appears. I just posted a possible example of a less naive approach. I don't claim this is perfect (or even necessarily good); I'm not trying to write a perfect name matcher. If that's what the OP wants he needs to state his requirements more clearly, and try to implement them. Our job here is not to do other people's work for them, it is to help them with problems they are having. I believe the op was misunderstanding the `{...}` part of the regex, so I helped with that problem.

Comment: @BenLee: it turned out that this was a homework question, so OP was actually cheating. I remove my answer and encourage others to do the same.

Comment: @thg435, there's nothing against the rules here saying you can't help with homework problems. Whether it's okay or not is dependent on the teacher's rules. And I think it would be unreasonable to speculate that they aren't allowed *any* outside help at all. The OP clearly put good-will effort into the regex and had it almost perfect, just needed another pair of eyes to see what wasn't working.

Comment: @thg435, for more on stackoverflow's policy on homework, along with responses from *actual programming teachers*, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: What SO rules clearly discourage is an extensive discussion in comments. So I'd say I'm ready with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need `{0,19}` not just `{19}`. The latter means "exactly 19 chars".

```
"John Smith".match(/^[A-Z][a-z]{0,19}[\s,][A-Z][a-z]{0,19}$/)
```

Of course, this regexp doesn't match many totally valid names like "José Ortega y Gasset" or "Charles de Batz-Castelmore d'Artagnan".

Depending upon how long acceptable surnames can be, you can replace "{0,19}" with "{1,19}" or "{2,19}". The same applies to first names.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]+[\s|,][A-Z][a-z]{1,19}$/.test("John Smith") // true
```

Comment: this regular expression allows numeric value. how can I achieve it

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
\b[A-Z]+.+[?^ ][A-Z].{1,19}|\b[A-Z]+.+[?^,][A-Z].{1,19}
```

This starts with the beginning of a word, checks that the first letter is caps, matches the first word up to a white space or comma, then checks to make sure the first letter of the next word is capitalized, and matches everything up to 19 characters after that.  Also makes sure each name is 2 or more characters long.

Answer (score 0):

The {19} means that the last name must have exactly 19 lowercase characters after the first uppercase character.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some expressions that might help for more complex names

```
(^[A-Z][a-z]*$) - A typical First Name or Last Name like Thomas
(^[A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z]*$) - names like McDonald
(^[A-Z][a-z]*(-|\s)[A-Z][a-z]*$) - names like Tonya-Smith or Tonya Smith
(^[A-Z]('|’)[A-Z][a-z]*$) - names like Tim O’Reilly
(^[a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]*$) - names like von Gogh
```